# In the component I want to implement nested route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The first route is working but when I change the path in the browser tab then it will be white page. like, first route path is: "/menu" it is working but when I put in the browser "/menu/style" it
is not working

````
import { Input, Modal, Pagination, Spin } from "antd";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Route, Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { MainCategory, MenuList, MenuStyle } from "../components";
import { CREATE_A_CATEGORY, GET_ALL_MENU } from "../graphql/modules";
import { errorNotify, successNotify, warnNotify } from "../util";
const Menu = ({ match: { url } }) => {
  console.log(url + "/style");
  return (
    <section id="item-menu">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={`${url}`} component={MenuList} />
          <Route path={`${url+ '/style'}`} component={MenuStyle} />
        </Switch>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Menu;```
````

Comment: Did you tried to switch your routes ? I think your problem have something to do with the *exact* props. Either try to invert you routes, meaning your "exact" route will be at the bottom, or try to remove that props.

Comment: Hi Chandelier Axel, I tried but not fixed

Comment: As per [this link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match), you should be using `path` instead of `url`, for nested routes